# UTF-16 instead of UTF-8 with mySQl to work with foreign languages

Tags: java, mysql, unicode, encoding

I have a JSP page that shows arabic strings from the database and I'm setting UTF-8 encoding in that way:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

The column that I defined in MySql Workbech 6 is VARCHAR(255).

In this way everything works fine and I can see Arabic strings in my browser.

Now the problem is that I want to use UTF-16 instead of UTF-8. I tried in many ways but without success.

1) First way.

I just changed the JSP directive in that way:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-16" pageEncoding="UTF-16"%>
```

But the page shows strange character.

2) Second attempt.

I tried not only to change the JSP, but also to change the collaction of my table to:

```
Collation: UTF-16 default collation
```

But in that way it doesn't work too.

what do you suggest me to do, in order to use UTF-16?

Comment: Why do you want to use UTF-16? It is not a suitable encoding for the web: there are myriad browser, language and database issues with it and it's almost invariably less efficient than UTF-8. Avoid.

Comment: I need to send it to an external platform in UTF-16. Is there then any way to convert it when needed?